# Determine if an object property is ko.observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) version 2.0.0

If I'm looping through all properties of an object, how can I test whether each property is a `ko.observable`?  Here's what I've tried so far:

```
    var vm = {
        prop: ko.observable(''),
        arr: ko.observableArray([]),
        func: ko.computed(function(){
            return this.prop + " computed";
        }, vm)
    };

    for (var key in vm) {
        console.log(key, 
            vm[key].constructor === ko.observable, 
            vm[key] instanceof ko.observable);
    }
```

But so far everything is false.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Knockout includes a function called `ko.isObservable()`.   You can call it like `ko.isObservable(vm[key])`.

Update from comment:

Here is a function to determine if something is a computed observable:

```
ko.isComputed = function (instance) {
    if ((instance === null) || (instance === undefined) || (instance.__ko_proto__ === undefined)) return false;
    if (instance.__ko_proto__ === ko.dependentObservable) return true;
    return ko.isComputed(instance.__ko_proto__); // Walk the prototype chain
};
```

UPDATE: If you are using KO 2.1+ - then you can use `ko.isComputed` directly.

Comment: Thank you.  Do you by chance know how to tell if an observable is computed?  I can determine if an observable is an observable array via `$.isArray(vm[key]())`, but do you know how to differentiate observables from a `ko.computed`??

Comment: KO 2.1 that should be out in the next few weeks will include a `ko.isComputed` function.  The code would be the equivalent to what I added to the answer above.

Answer (score 29):

Knockout has the following function which I think is what you are looking for:

```
ko.isObservable(vm[key])
```

Answer (score 3):

To tack on to RP Niemeyer's answer, if you're simply looking to determine if something is "subscribable" (which is most often the case). Then [`ko.isSubscribable`](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/3d7cf10fa8d0452d1c391ebfd46b3ec1f81ae9d5/src/subscribables/subscribable.js#L188) is also available.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using

```
ko.utils.unwrapObservable(vm.key)
```

**Update**: As of version 2.3.0, `ko.unwrap` was added as substitute for `ko.utils.unwrapObservable`

Comment: That unwraps an observable.  It doesn't test whether a property is an observable.

Comment: You're right. But usually if you need to know to get the actual observable value ;)

Comment: It provides a valid way to access a property that may or may not be observable however it doesn't answer the question per se.