# Knockout js set multple observables together

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I wonder if there is any way to update the whole viewmodel with a single object.
For instance, saying our viewmodel is as follows:

```
    Function ExampleViewModel(){
     this.name = ko.observable();
     this.lastname = ko.observable();
     this.phone = ko.observable();
    }
    var viewmodel = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindinings(viewmodel);
```

And then suppose I create an object like:

```
    var newObject = {name: "newname", lastname: "lastname", phone: 432}
```

Instead of setting  individually each observable as follows:

```
        viewmodel.name(newObject.name);
             or
        viewmodel.name(newObject.name).lastname(newObject.lastname) etc etc
```

Could I update the whole viewmodel doing something like:

```
        viewmodel.update(newObject)?
```

Comment: The mapping plugin can help facilitate that. Though, I think it will still re-render the page for every change as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through the object:

```
for (var key in newObject) {
    if (viewModel[key] && ko.isObservable(viewModel[key])) {
        viewModel[key](newObject[key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably at least check that the property on the `viewModel` is actually an observable. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625591/determine-if-an-object-property-is-ko-observable

Comment: Is there are good reason to go with this rather than use the mapping plugin?

Comment: @SanderRoes Sure, but the mapping plugin would be one line of code!

Comment: Sure you can use the plugin then. But if these are the only requirements, it seems overkill to use a plugin if you can also do it with a few lines of code.