# The purpose of __ko_proto__ in knockout.js?

Tags: knockout.js

I want to ask the purpose of a statement in knockout.js source code. Thank you.

```
ko.observable = function (initialValue) {
    var _latestValue = initialValue;

    function observable(newValue) {
        return _latestValue;
    }
    observable.__ko_proto__ = ko.observable;   **// <-- what's the purpose of this line??**

    ko.subscribable.call(observable);
    return observable;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing I have seen it helpful for is testing for observable properties. As found here
[Determine if an object property is ko.observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625591/determine-if-an-object-property-is-ko-observable)

Answer (score 1):

The `__ko_proto__` property is how Knockout knows that something is an observable. Most bindings can accept either an observable or a plain value and use `ko.unwrap` to get the actual value. `ko.unwrap` uses `ko.isObservable`, which checks the `__ko_proto__` property.